# WriteableBitmap PixelBuffer Stream Length Too Small

Tags: c#, buffer, windows-runtime, writeablebitmap

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to copy the pixel buffer for one WriteableBitmap over to another WriteableBitmap essentially giving a copy of the WriteableBitmap object. However, when I try to do this I run into an issue where the second WriteableBitmap's stream length is too short to hold all the values of the first WriteableBitmap.
I posted my code below. Keep in mind that I'm capturing the original data from a webcam. However, when I compare the "ps" object's stream size to wb1 and wb2, ps's size is much smaller than both of them. What I'm confused about is why wb2 stream size is smaller than wb1's. Thanks for any help.

```
private MemoryStream originalStream = new MemoryStream();
WriteableBitmap wb1 = new WriteableBitmap((int)photoBox.Width, (int)photoBox.Height);
WriteableBitmap wb2 = new WriteableBitmap((int)photoBox.Width, (int)photoBox.Height);

ImageEncodingProperties imageProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
var ps = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

await mc.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imageProperties, ps);
await ps.FlushAsync();

ps.Seek(0);

wb1.SetSource(ps);
(wb1.PixelBuffer.AsStream()).CopyTo(originalStream); // this works

originalStream.Position = 0;
originalStream.CopyTo(wb2.PixelBuffer.AsStream()); // this line gives me the error: "Unable to expand length of this stream beyond its capacity"

Image img = new Image(); 
img.Source = wb2; // my hope is to treat this as it's own entity and modify this image independently of wb1 or originalStream

photoBox.Source =wb1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you do new WriteableBitmap(w, h) and then call SetSource() to an image of a different resolution - the bitmap's size will change (it won't be the w x h passed in the constructor). It's likely that your photoBox.Width/Height are different than what your CapturePhotoToStreamAsync() call returns (I am assuming the image is captured at the default or preconfigured camera settings, while photoBox is just a control on screen).

How about just doing someting like this

```
ps.Seek(0);
wb1.SetSource(ps);
ps.Seek(0);
wb2.SetSource(ps);
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was that easy. I have a feeling I might run into memory management issues later on with ps, but that is a problem with my app not your solution. Thanks for pointing out the obvious Filip!

Comment: Filip, I have come across XamlToolkit. 
WritableBitmapRenderExtension.Render(image); giving "Unable to expand length of this stream beyond its capacity". I have just created an XAML image programmatically & rendered it using this method & giving me this error. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, that API isn's supported anymore. Use [`RenderTargetBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap) instead

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a writter from the PixelBuffer and use it to copy the stream.
The AsStream method should be used to read the buffer, not to write into it.

Have a look to 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/winappswithcsharp/thread/2b499ac5-8bc8-4259-a144-842bd756bfe2

for a piece of code

Comment: Isn't that what the CopyTo method is doing though because doesn't AsStream() just take the PixelBuffer and return an IBuffer object? Also which PixelBuffer are you talking about?